# Specifying the order of jq results

Tags: bash, jq

I want to process some json from reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/videos/top.json?limit=3

```
{
  "kind": "Listing",
  "data": {
    "modhash": "",
    "children": [
      {
        "kind": "t3",
        "data": {
          "contest_mode": false,
          "banned_by": null,
          "domain": "youtube.com",
          "subreddit": "videos",
          "selftext_html": null,
          "selftext": "",
          "likes": null,
          "suggested_sort": null,
          "user_reports": [],
          "secure_media": {
            "oembed": {
              "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
              "version": "1.0",
              "title": "SpaceX Interplanetary Transport System",
              "thumbnail_width": 480,
              "height": 338,
              "width": 600,
              "html": "&lt;iframe width=\"600\" height=\"338\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/0qo78R_yYFA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
              "author_name": "SpaceX",
              "thumbnail_height": 360,
              "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0qo78R_yYFA/hqdefault.jpg",
              "type": "video",
              "provider_name": "YouTube",
              "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/spacexchannel"
            },
            "type": "youtube.com"
          },
          "saved": false,
          "id": "54rrjl",
          "gilded": 0,
          "secure_media_embed": {
            "content": "&lt;iframe width=\"600\" height=\"338\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/0qo78R_yYFA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
            "width": 600,
            "scrolling": false,
            "height": 338
          },
          "clicked": false,
          "report_reasons": null,
          "author": "jclishman",
          "media": {
            "oembed": {
              "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
              "version": "1.0",
              "title": "SpaceX Interplanetary Transport System",
              "thumbnail_width": 480,
              "height": 338,
              "width": 600,
              "html": "&lt;iframe width=\"600\" height=\"338\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/0qo78R_yYFA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
              "author_name": "SpaceX",
              "thumbnail_height": 360,
              "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0qo78R_yYFA/hqdefault.jpg",
              "type": "video",
              "provider_name": "YouTube",
              "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/spacexchannel"
            },
            "type": "youtube.com"
          },
          "name": "t3_54rrjl",
          "score": 4947,
          "approved_by": null,
          "over_18": false,
          "removal_reason": null,
          "hidden": false,
          "preview": {
            "images": [
              {
                "source": {
                  "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/UmxPKXyvkXx8ap0ugxIgFu2yB00xZPrnR80zTb-kRlc.jpg?s=bdeffae704dbca1cf477f09608479cd9",
                  "width": 480,
                  "height": 360
                },
                "resolutions": [
                  {
                    "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/UmxPKXyvkXx8ap0ugxIgFu2yB00xZPrnR80zTb-kRlc.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=108&amp;s=45a9e73c27ba9d344b75793ac6951567",
                    "width": 108,
                    "height": 81
                  },
                  {
                    "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/UmxPKXyvkXx8ap0ugxIgFu2yB00xZPrnR80zTb-kRlc.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=216&amp;s=a59e97b76b1347e2f26333ec2c7d50c1",
                    "width": 216,
                    "height": 162
                  },
                  {
                    "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/UmxPKXyvkXx8ap0ugxIgFu2yB00xZPrnR80zTb-kRlc.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=320&amp;s=631ddd2156d83ee7fec1c6f4c98c5c4b",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 240
                  }
                ],
                "variants": {},
                "id": "0sz_ShT1IlShzb117hpblwELVvmEgpD3n_WCpw94VN4"
              }
            ]
          },
          "thumbnail": "http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/TLG2iK4WvyVntpjBcKPIyRinq2zKEvOuK8z0klQhmvY.jpg",
          "subreddit_id": "t5_2qh1e",
          "edited": false,
          "link_flair_css_class": null,
          "author_flair_css_class": null,
          "downs": 0,
          "mod_reports": [],
          "archived": false,
          "media_embed": {
            "content": "&lt;iframe width=\"600\" height=\"338\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/0qo78R_yYFA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
            "width": 600,
            "scrolling": false,
            "height": 338
          },
          "post_hint": "rich:video",
          "is_self": false,
          "hide_score": false,
          "permalink": "/r/videos/comments/54rrjl/spacex_interplanetary_transport_system/",
          "locked": false,
          "stickied": false,
          "created": 1475026717,
          "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qo78R_yYFA",
          "author_flair_text": null,
          "quarantine": false,
          "title": "SpaceX Interplanetary Transport System",
          "created_utc": 1474997917,
          "link_flair_text": null,
          "distinguished": null,
          "num_comments": 1077,
          "visited": false,
          "num_reports": null,
          "ups": 4947
        }
      },
      {
        "kind": "t3",
        "data": {
          "contest_mode": false,
          "banned_by": null,
          "domain": "youtube.com",
          "subreddit": "videos",
          "selftext_html": null,
          "selftext": "",
          "likes": null,
          "suggested_sort": null,
          "user_reports": [],
          "secure_media": {
            "type": "youtube.com",
            "oembed": {
              "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
              "title": "35 years Backwards thru Time with Sam Klemke (Time Lapse)",
              "type": "video",
              "html": "&lt;iframe width=\"459\" height=\"344\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/K2xTBHyfOks?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
              "thumbnail_width": 480,
              "height": 344,
              "width": 459,
              "version": "1.0",
              "author_name": "MisterEsoteric",
              "thumbnail_height": 360,
              "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/K2xTBHyfOks/hqdefault.jpg",
              "provider_name": "YouTube",
              "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/MisterEsoteric"
            }
          },
          "saved": false,
          "id": "54r1gh",
          "gilded": 0,
          "secure_media_embed": {
            "content": "&lt;iframe width=\"459\" height=\"344\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/K2xTBHyfOks?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
            "width": 459,
            "scrolling": false,
            "height": 344
          },
          "clicked": false,
          "report_reasons": null,
          "author": "a_shootin_star",
          "media": {
            "type": "youtube.com",
            "oembed": {
              "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
              "title": "35 years Backwards thru Time with Sam Klemke (Time Lapse)",
              "type": "video",
              "html": "&lt;iframe width=\"459\" height=\"344\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/K2xTBHyfOks?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
              "thumbnail_width": 480,
              "height": 344,
              "width": 459,
              "version": "1.0",
              "author_name": "MisterEsoteric",
              "thumbnail_height": 360,
              "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/K2xTBHyfOks/hqdefault.jpg",
              "provider_name": "YouTube",
              "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/MisterEsoteric"
            }
          },
          "name": "t3_54r1gh",
          "score": 4631,
          "approved_by": null,
          "over_18": false,
          "removal_reason": null,
          "hidden": false,
          "preview": {
            "images": [
              {
                "source": {
                  "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/ff7YtFDYgwsOuge92mnUE4rUT2fnJOctQJ6nJgMZoj8.jpg?s=21cd790f369febedcece048a2dc33714",
                  "width": 480,
                  "height": 360
                },
                "resolutions": [
                  {
                    "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/ff7YtFDYgwsOuge92mnUE4rUT2fnJOctQJ6nJgMZoj8.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=108&amp;s=42827db4a8eef7d90c8fd35339f134c8",
                    "width": 108,
                    "height": 81
                  },
                  {
                    "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/ff7YtFDYgwsOuge92mnUE4rUT2fnJOctQJ6nJgMZoj8.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=216&amp;s=a33acbee6c5ea92382fa5c7c0f76979c",
                    "width": 216,
                    "height": 162
                  },
                  {
                    "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/ff7YtFDYgwsOuge92mnUE4rUT2fnJOctQJ6nJgMZoj8.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=320&amp;s=c7c2a52e55089b17da7fc0d35c57b484",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 240
                  }
                ],
                "variants": {},
                "id": "fLOkvXgiEKsZnefFoNcOTKy0x6dk9ODi6cLVi9MMHGo"
              }
            ]
          },
          "thumbnail": "http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/RZUqE22jXxl1xbkqptl99WMkyLwYxXOjTSgd-Uy7nAE.jpg",
          "subreddit_id": "t5_2qh1e",
          "edited": false,
          "link_flair_css_class": null,
          "author_flair_css_class": null,
          "downs": 0,
          "mod_reports": [],
          "archived": false,
          "media_embed": {
            "content": "&lt;iframe width=\"459\" height=\"344\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/K2xTBHyfOks?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
            "width": 459,
            "scrolling": false,
            "height": 344
          },
          "post_hint": "rich:video",
          "is_self": false,
          "hide_score": false,
          "permalink": "/r/videos/comments/54r1gh/there_is_a_man_who_filmed_himself_annually_for_35/",
          "locked": false,
          "stickied": false,
          "created": 1475018163,
          "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2xTBHyfOks",
          "author_flair_text": null,
          "quarantine": false,
          "title": "There is a man who filmed himself annually for 35 years and made a video going backwards to 1977. [ORIGINAL] - [06:31]",
          "created_utc": 1474989363,
          "link_flair_text": null,
          "distinguished": null,
          "num_comments": 1345,
          "visited": false,
          "num_reports": null,
          "ups": 4631
        }
      },
      {
        "kind": "t3",
        "data": {
          "contest_mode": false,
          "banned_by": null,
          "domain": "youtube.com",
          "subreddit": "videos",
          "selftext_html": null,
          "selftext": "",
          "likes": null,
          "suggested_sort": null,
          "user_reports": [],
          "secure_media": {
            "type": "youtube.com",
            "oembed": {
              "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
              "version": "1.0",
              "title": "How Patton Oswalt &amp; His Daughter Are Coping With His Wife's Passing  - CONAN on TBS",
              "author_name": "Team Coco",
              "height": 338,
              "width": 600,
              "html": "&lt;iframe width=\"600\" height=\"338\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/iuLKSvoK8KA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
              "thumbnail_width": 480,
              "thumbnail_height": 360,
              "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iuLKSvoK8KA/hqdefault.jpg",
              "type": "video",
              "provider_name": "YouTube",
              "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/teamcoco"
            }
          },
          "saved": false,
          "id": "54s0sm",
          "gilded": 0,
          "secure_media_embed": {
            "content": "&lt;iframe width=\"600\" height=\"338\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/iuLKSvoK8KA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
            "width": 600,
            "scrolling": false,
            "height": 338
          },
          "clicked": false,
          "report_reasons": null,
          "author": "bruhfamsquad",
          "media": {
            "type": "youtube.com",
            "oembed": {
              "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
              "version": "1.0",
              "title": "How Patton Oswalt &amp; His Daughter Are Coping With His Wife's Passing  - CONAN on TBS",
              "author_name": "Team Coco",
              "height": 338,
              "width": 600,
              "html": "&lt;iframe width=\"600\" height=\"338\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/iuLKSvoK8KA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
              "thumbnail_width": 480,
              "thumbnail_height": 360,
              "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iuLKSvoK8KA/hqdefault.jpg",
              "type": "video",
              "provider_name": "YouTube",
              "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/teamcoco"
            }
          },
          "name": "t3_54s0sm",
          "score": 3732,
          "approved_by": null,
          "over_18": false,
          "removal_reason": null,
          "hidden": false,
          "preview": {
            "images": [
              {
                "source": {
                  "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/mY4uWOaN90_K5IMcDhz_FtmLtZFyGQZYiMNeSljv9xs.jpg?s=e0fa03c1cfbec29d8d4a2745fea0094c",
                  "width": 480,
                  "height": 360
                },
                "resolutions": [
                  {
                    "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/mY4uWOaN90_K5IMcDhz_FtmLtZFyGQZYiMNeSljv9xs.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=108&amp;s=c51d04dbef9f3121ec0955d6f7be6cbd",
                    "width": 108,
                    "height": 81
                  },
                  {
                    "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/mY4uWOaN90_K5IMcDhz_FtmLtZFyGQZYiMNeSljv9xs.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=216&amp;s=f0e15bfd6bc17745be698e670de399f9",
                    "width": 216,
                    "height": 162
                  },
                  {
                    "url": "https://i.redditmedia.com/mY4uWOaN90_K5IMcDhz_FtmLtZFyGQZYiMNeSljv9xs.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=320&amp;s=648cdbd8af77fa7b6542a038e6f8fc86",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 240
                  }
                ],
                "variants": {},
                "id": "JAjE3xovazbxxz0FI8I3lwu2TWLLRVxOg6hPeoDPrWI"
              }
            ]
          },
          "thumbnail": "http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/R89XcpIkm4e6NqHhiNzE6JmPU6kxVibipzbesVYg6oY.jpg",
          "subreddit_id": "t5_2qh1e",
          "edited": false,
          "link_flair_css_class": null,
          "author_flair_css_class": null,
          "downs": 0,
          "mod_reports": [],
          "archived": false,
          "media_embed": {
            "content": "&lt;iframe width=\"600\" height=\"338\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/iuLKSvoK8KA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
            "width": 600,
            "scrolling": false,
            "height": 338
          },
          "post_hint": "rich:video",
          "is_self": false,
          "hide_score": false,
          "permalink": "/r/videos/comments/54s0sm/how_patton_oswalt_his_daughter_are_coping_with/",
          "locked": false,
          "stickied": false,
          "created": 1475029674,
          "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuLKSvoK8KA",
          "author_flair_text": null,
          "quarantine": false,
          "title": "How Patton Oswalt &amp; His Daughter Are Coping With His Wife's Passing",
          "created_utc": 1475000874,
          "link_flair_text": null,
          "distinguished": null,
          "num_comments": 565,
          "visited": false,
          "num_reports": null,
          "ups": 3732
        }
      }
    ],
    "after": "t3_54s0sm",
    "before": null
  }
}
```

```
$ curl https://www.reddit.com/r/videos/top.json\?limit\=3 | \
jq -r '(.data.children|.[].data.title),(.data.children|.[].data.url),(.data.children|.[].data.score)'
```

It produces the following output:

```
SpaceX Interplanetary Transport System
There is a man who filmed himself annually for 35 years and made a video going backwards to 1977. [ORIGINAL] - [06:31]
Japanese men trying to pronounce "Massachusetts"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qo78R_yYFA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2xTBHyfOks
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69iSXks1bes
4874
4644
5075
```

I want to get the following output:

```
SpaceX Interplanetary Transport System, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qo78R_yYFA, 4874
There is a man who filmed himself annually for 35 years and made a video going backwards to 1977. [ORIGINAL] - [06:31], https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2xTBHyfOks, 4644
Japanese men trying to pronounce "Massachusetts", https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69iSXks1bes, 5075
```

How can I adjust the way that the results are returned?

Comment: edit - add the json returned by curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields that you're interested in are in the `data` objects of each of the `children`.  You'll want to keep them together so you should limit how many times you go through the child items, just do it once.  And it seems you're outputting in a CSV format, so you could use `@csv` for that.  Just put the properties in an array first.

```
$ curl ... | jq -r '.data.children[].data | [.title, .url, .score] | @csv
```